# Can't SSH to Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012-r2, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I have setup OpenSSH on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials machine and have sshd running as a service.  I have opened up incoming traffic in the firewall rules on port 22 for TCP.  I generated keys via ssh-keygen on my client machine and copied the public key to the server and appended to authorized keys.  When I attempt to use cygwin to ssh to the server, I keep getting connection timed out.

What things do I have to check/enable/etc...to further test this and allow ssh connections to this server?

Comment: run on the server `netstat -aon | find /i "22" `does that give you any results

Comment: running that command in cygwin on the server gives me No such file or directory on both '/i' & '22'

Comment: run it on the cmd of the server2012 box not in cygwin

Comment: This comes back:  TCP    0.0.0.0:22    0.0.0.0:0     LISTENING       8512

Comment: Can you ping the box from another workstation?

Comment: Ping actually comes back with "Request timed out"

Comment: ping timeout isn't always a bad thing. If you install putty on the server 2012 box can you connect then?

Comment: I installed Putty on the server and still can't connect

Comment: Can you run the command I gave you above again, this time look for the number at the end (8512 in your above response). Then open task manager on the server. Add the PID to the shown column and check that openssh has the same nmuber next to it (again 8512 in the above response)

Comment: Yes - the sshd.exe service is running with PID 8512

Comment: Short of an over zealous windows firewall, or another anti-virus/firewall blocking it. I'm out of ideas I'm afraid.